# How to upload image file in android using web api

Tags: android, file-upload

I want to upload images using web api. I tried to get binary data of images and send them as string or json parameter. But binary data string is too long and after some time the application was stopping.

Web api was writed in c#. And i have some images, i have to upload these when user clicks sync button. How can i do that?

Answer (score -1):

you need to send the data over internet in XML form. convert your data information in XML form and after that send it to API. many API receive data in only XML format.